# Jquery AJAX post failed from ASP.Net User Control to ASMX service

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, user-controls

I'm working on an ASP.Net user control, which is using Jquery UI for rendering controls such as modal dialog, accordion, etc.
`I've ajax post method in the javascript file. The javascript file lies in JS folder under Root.`

```
    function ajaxPost(someData) {
      var serviceUrl = "../Test.asmx/eidTasks";
      var param="{'data':'" + someData + "'}";

      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: serviceUrl,
        data: param,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: ajaxPostSuccess,
        error: ajaxPostFailed
      });
    }

    function ajaxPostSuccess(){
      alert("Post Success");
    }

    function ajaxPostFailed(){
      alert("Post Failed");
    }
```

My `ajaxPostFailed` always gets triggered. I suspect that the issue is I'm not able to reference the `.asmx` service correctly. I saw while debugging that the service was not at all hit. Any pointers what could be the correct way to give the **service URL** path here.

I've tested the service separately and it does have the `[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]` block uncommented to allow AJAX calls.

**EDIT**

How can I call a webmethod (wrapped in a asmx file) from a JS file? Provided, both are part of same ASP.Net solution with the .js file inside JS folder under ROOT directory. The asmx web service is directly beneath ROOT.

Comment: Have you tried _standing_ the JS file?

Comment: What's the actual error that the JavaScript code is seeing?  When you debug this in your browser, what is the request being made to the server and what is the server's response?  Just alerting that the "post failed" kind of obscures helpful messages.

Comment: I might be wrong here... but aren't asmx files SOAP interfaces? so wouldn't you need to send XML...

Comment: You could try to enter the full path to the service, would look something like this `var serviceUrl = "http://localhost/Test.asmx/eidTasks";`

Comment: @henrikm: That doesn't work. Thanks for the response though.

Comment: I'm much of a novice in using jquery ajax and calling services. So far, I've worked mostly in server side code. Making the question much more simpler now. Please see my `EDIT`

Comment: To get any more help with your issue, you really should include the 
error message. Replace the error handling in you ajax with this: `error: function (err) { console.log(err); }` This will print out the error message in the console of your browser.

Comment: Tried this way and had no luck. I think because of the complexity involved. Anyways, I've found another approach without doing any AJAX call at all. Suits requirements, then suits me. Cheers. See this **[post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20244084/resizing-jquery-dialog-div-on-iframe-content-height-change-where-iframe-contain)**

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is with the .asmx file not being correctly referenced from your JScript, try resolving the path using `ResolveClientUrl()` method. For e.g., `var serviceUrl = '<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/Test.asmx")%>'+"/eidTasks"`

Comment: When I added an alert after this statement. I got the following:`<%= ResolveClientUrl("~/Test.asmx")%>/eidTasks`. Am I doing something wrong?