# Resizing jQuery dialog div on iFrame content height change, where iframe contained in dialog

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, iframe

I've a jquery dialog div. The div contains an iFrame to another ASP.Net page on the same domain. The iframe source page also contains jquery accordion control. Whenever the dialog is opened and accordion are expanded/collapsed, I need to resize the dialog box. Currently the contents are getting chopped off. Please note again that the dialog wraps the accordion within an iframe. I'm breaking my head against the wall to make things work. If somebody have a solution to this, then please help me out.
Note: Everything is in same domain.

**SOLVED**
See my ANSWER below.

Comment: please provide some code samples of what you have tried

Comment: I would like to know why the question was downvoted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is for Same Origin (i.e. same domain). If you have access to iframe source page, put the following inline function globally:

```
    var iFrameIdOnParentSelector = "#Replace_with_iframe_id_on_parent";
    var iFrameContentSelector = "#Replace_with_content_id_on_iframe_src_page";
    function fireiFrameResize(iFrameIdOnParentSelector, iFrameContentSelector) {
     var frame = $(iFrameIdOnParentSelector, window.parent.document);
     var height = jQuery(iFrameContentSelector).height();
     var width = jQuery(iFrameContentSelector).width();
     frame.height(height);
     frame.width(width);
    }
```

In your accordion call, add `activate` property. Trigger the `fireiFrameResize()` method with it. The function will run on every expand and collapse of accordion.

```
     $("#accordionDiv").accordion({
      collapsible: true,
      active: false,
      heightStyle: "content",
      activate: function (event, ui) {
        fireiFrameResize(iFrameIdOnParentSelector, iFrameContentSelector);
      }
     });
```

On your calling page/control, where iFrame control is there, set it's height and width to some initial default. Do not set the dialog height and width containing the iframe. It'll take the iframe height and width by default. Please note the following:

- My iframe is a server control inside a custom user control.
- Since, iframe is a server control here, so I set `ClientIdMode="Static"`. This avoids runtime id creation by ASP.Net engine.

Cheers. :)

Comment: Thank you all for the effort. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the child iframe to talk to the parent window when the accordion is toggled.

```
$yourAccordion.on('open', function(e){
  if(window.top && window.top.resizeDialog)
     window.top.resizeDialog($(window).width(),$(window).height());
});
```

Then in your parent page, have a global function called `resizeDialog`

```
window.resizeDialog = function(w,h){
  $('#dialog').find('iframe').attr({
    width: w,
    height: h
  });
};
```

Note: You'll most likely need to account for animation timing etc. You could also include this in the `step` function of the jQuery `animate` method you use to open/close the accordion to make it a bit smoother.

Comment: Quite right, but couldn't make it work in my scenario. However, I followed another approach to achieve it. Check my solution. Cheers.